# Asynchronous API callback Design question

Tags: silverlight, asynchronous, callback, api-design

I'm using Silverlight with RIA Services, which are asynchronous by nature. The question isn't specific to this technology choice though.

I want to wrap an asynchronous call, for a web service for example, and provide my own simplified and loosely coupled API (ex: repository over DomainClient).

So far, I have the following style of asynchronous methods in my interfaces:

```
public void DoAsyncWork(Action<AsyncWorkResult<someResultType>> callback);
```

and I'm considering adding the following overloads:

```
public void DoAsyncWork(Action<someResultType> onSuccess, 
                        Action<Exception> onException);
```

and

```
public void DoAsyncWork(Action<someResultType> onSuccess,
                        Action<Exception> onException,
                        Action finally);
```

the `onSuccess` action would only execute if the asynchronous call completed successfully, the `onException` executes in case there was an error reported by the call, and the `finally` woul execute at the end in either case.

My question is, having implemented the first style which is kind of "the general one", and the most used (as far as I can tell), should I implement the other two? are they worth the investement in development and maintenance?

This question is about the design aspect, independent of any requirements.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Cory: I didn't add the "Silverlight" tag on purpose here, because as I said, I'm focusing only on the API Design aspect. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: The best API designs can look wildly different depending on the language/framework you're using.  I'd say it's important information, but maybe not.

Comment: @Cory: OK, fair enough :)
But where did your answer go? I didn't use the pattern you referred to much, and I was going to learn more about it. Then I found your answer was gone :s

Comment: I deleted it when I realized it didn't quite answer your question.  I guess I'll undelete :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say keep it to one really good, consistent API if possible.

It's probably best to mimic the async APIs that already exist in .NET, which allow you to use the built-in exception handling syntax:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginAsyncWork(AsyncCallback callback, object state);
public SomeResultType EndAsyncWork(IAsyncResult res);
```

Which is used like:

```
BeginAsyncWork(res =>
{
    // BeginAsyncWork calls this once it completes, even on error.

    // res is IAsyncResult -- the same one BeginAsyncWork returns.
    // res.AsyncState is whatever the users passed in the 'state' parameter.

    try
    {
        // To get the result, and possibly an exception, EndAsyncWork is called.
        SomeResultType r = EndAsyncWork(res);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // EndAsyncWork throws the exception.
    }
    finally
    {
        //
    }
}, null);
```